# Generating Distributions From Random Number Generators

Tags: r, distributions, random-generation, c++

## Background

I am working on developing a R package that focuses on implementation of pseudo-Random Number Generators (pRNGs) from scratch. To date I have successfully programmed a [Linear Congruential Generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) takes a seed and the relevant parameters.

The code I have for doing it is the following:

```c
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <math.h>
using namespace Rcpp;


NumericVector lcg(int seed, int n,  long long m  = 65537,  long long a = 75,   long long c = 74) {
  NumericVector generated_numbers;
  // Presetting Parameters as per ZX81
  int number = seed;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    number = (a * number + c)  % m;
    generated_numbers.push_back(number);

  }

  return generated_numbers;
}
```

An example of using this code in R is:

```
random_numbers <- lcg(1234, 1000)
# Plot numbers to see that they are random
plot(random_numbers)
```

## Question

I am curious about moving things to the "next-step" and using these RNGs to simulate random variables from distributions relevant specified parameters (e.g. Normal, Gamma, Bernolli/Binomial, Poisson, etc.).

I know its possible to do this by using the [Inverse Probability Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling) if we have a uniform distribution function. However, I'm not sure how to generate uniform random variables from the numbers generated with a pRNG.

How would one go about doing this? What would some example code look like for this?

Answer (score 3):

I assume you know that's not a very good generator -- for example, if you get 1000 numbers from it that way they will all be different, whereas 1000 random numbers from 1..65537 would be very unlikely to all be different.

However, leaving that aside, you can produce uniform numbers on [0,1] by dividing your numbers by 65536, ie, `m-1`: the largest value you can get for the numbers.  Once you have that, you can use eg `qnorm` or `qbinom` or `qpois` or `qgamma` in R to do the probability transform to Normal or Binomial or Poisson or Gamma or whatever.

Comment: Never thought of approaching it like that. Wow! That's really simple. 

I am in the process of trying to program a few pRNGs just for experimentation so the LCG one set of code that I managed to complete to my satisfaction thus far.